# BroadcastReceiver.onReceive is not called for PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Following this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#receiver I created my own project. Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="alex.broadcast.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Code:

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
final String logTag = "BroadcastReceiverSample";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.i(logTag, "Call state: " + state);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.i(logTag, "Phone number: " + phoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Running this sample on Android simulator, I see that it is successfully installed. However, onReceive function is never called. I make incoming call using:

```
telnet localhost 5554
gsm call 12345678
```

Emulator shows incoming call, but onReceive is not called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyPhoneReceiver">
                        ^ note the dot
```

Also, the location of the permission is wrong, it should be a child of `<manifest>` not of `<Application>`.

Comment: I made this change, but onReceive still not called. Actually, I see that this program never starts. It looks like something is wrong with registering for phone event.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 6 dont forget to allow the permission :

```
onCreate(){
if (
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            )
        {
            requestPermission();
        }else {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
}
 private void requestPermission() {
    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:{
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
    }
}
```